# What does $F:2^\nu \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While I was watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3u_hvxayDY, which is about submodular optimization, I found $F:2^\nu \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in about 1:00 in the video.

Could anyone please clarify what it means?

I guess that means a function $F$ gets any subset of $\nu$ as an input and it outputs a real number. Am I correct?

Comment: "I guess that means a function $F$  gets any subset of $\nu$ as an input and it outputs a real number." Yessss!!!

Comment: In the video she refers to the Power Set. The power set of $v$ is the set of all subsets of $v$, including the empty set and $v$ itself. Sometimes denoted as $P(v)$, or $2^v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a function that maps subsets of $\nu$ to real numbers.

So, why is this notation used?

In set theory, if we have two sets $A$ and $B$, the notation $A^B$ (or ${}^BA$ by some authors) commonly denotes the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$, that is each function $f:B\to A$ is a member of $A^B$, and nothing else is.

Another common thing in set theory, is that the natural number $n$ is a shorthand for the set $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$. In particular, $2$ denotes the set $\{0,1\}$.

---

So what is $2^\nu$?

Well, it's the set of functions $f:\nu\to\{0,1\}$. Each such function $f$ uniquely describes a subset $X\subseteq\nu$ in the following way: if $a$ is an element of $\nu$, then we say that $a\in X$ if and only if $f(a)=1$.

Conversely, each subset $X\subseteq\nu$ uniquely describes a function $f:\nu \to \{0,1\}$, where we let $f$ send an element $a\in \nu$ to $1$ if and only if $a\in X$, and send it to $0$ otherwise.

Such function $f$ is called the *characteristic function* of the subset $X$. You could consider $f$ and $X$ represent the same concept in two different ways.

---

Thus, in conclusion, $F:2^\nu\to \Bbb R$ is a map of the set of characteristic functions (hence essentially of subsets of $\nu$) to real numbers.